# After something done OR after something is done

Tags: word-usage

I would like to know which one is correct.

I will ask the staff to close your previous approval after your new application approved.

OR

I will ask the staff to close your previous approval after your new application is approved.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We will do this after it is approved.

You are saying the state needs to change to *be approved* (it is approved).